Load Flutter assets in Android Jetpack Glance
I am trying to load an asset in my Glance Composable with the AssetManager from Flutter. I found this documentation but it still uses Java and seems like Glance uses a different context than the application itself.
What I tried:
@Composable()
fun IconImage(modifier: GlanceModifier = GlanceModifier) {
        val assetPath : String = "assets/test.png"
        val assetLookupKey =  FlutterLoader().getLookupKeyForAsset(assetPath)
        val inputStream: InputStream = LocalContext.current.assets.open(assetLookupKey)
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
        Image(
            ImageProvider(bitmap), modifier = modifier, contentDescription = null
        )
}


This worked:
@Composable()
fun IconImage(modifier: GlanceModifier = GlanceModifier) {
    val assetPath : String = "assets/test.png"
    val loader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader()
    val assetLookupKey = loader.getLookupKeyForAsset(assetPath)
    val inputStream: InputStream = LocalContext.current.assets.open(assetLookupKey)
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
    Image(
      ImageProvider(bitmap), modifier = modifier, contentDescription = null
    )
}

